# How to select second row in R?

Tags: r

I want to select a second row from a table (or array?) but it returns an error.

```
a <- readLines(stdin(), n=1)
```

I enter `5 4 3 2 1 4 5 6 7 6 5 4`

```
data <- strsplit(a, " ")
leafplot <- table(data)
leafplot[,2]
```

Then it returns an error

```
Error in `[.default`(leafplot, , 2) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Eventually `leafplot` has not two dimensions. Test it: `str(leafplot)` or `dim(leafplot)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(leafplot)$Freq
# [1] 1 1 1 3 3 2 1
```

Or

```
as.matrix(leafplot)[, 1]
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
# 1 1 1 3 3 2 1
```